Convergence issue of Temperature Dependent Lattice constant using CPMD
I am trying to find out temperature dependent lattice constant (Silicon) using CPMD (NPT-MD). If I want the lattice parameters at 300 K, should I set temp 300 K in both &cell and &ion card? I have seen a paper using an NPT ensemble and set temperature only &ion card (not &cell card), that's why I am confused. However, I am following the steps below.
step1) Relax cell using pw.x
step2) relax electrons to the ground state using cp.x
step3) Add some random displacement to ion using cp.x
Step4) Start CPMD (NPT ensemble) using 'vc-cp'(I have shared the input file of step 4 below)
After finishing the simulation, I checked the Si.evp file ( this file is also shared below) to check the convergence. Looking at the file I notice that the cell temperature (image is given below) didn't converge to 300 K (as I set, already 20000 steps done). But Ion temperature (image is given below) looks good to me. If I want to find out lattice constant at 300 K, what should I do now? Run the simulations more steps until the cell temperature converge to 300 K? Also if you see the average physical quantities in the output, It shows that temperature 300.56059 K (I am confused whether it is ion temperature or whole system temperature)
Input file (NPT ensemble)
   

 &control
            calculation = 'vc-cp'
            restart_mode = 'reset_counters'
            prefix = 'si'
            outdir = './outdir'
            pseudo_dir = './'
            nstep=3000, iprint=10, isave=100,
            dt=5.0,
            ndr=52, ndw=53,        ! folder for reading and writing
        /
        &system
            ibrav=8, celldm(1)=10.6407620646, celldm(2) = 1, celldm(3) = 1
            nat=8, ntyp=1,
            ecutwfc=50, ecutrho=400
            nr1b=20, nr2b=20, nr3b=20,  !For US PP specify no. of points for FFT of aug. charge
        /
        &electrons
            electron_dynamics = 'verlet'         
            electron_velocities = 'zero'
            emass=300.
            orthogonalization='ortho', ortho_eps=1d-11
        /
        &ions
            ion_dynamics = 'verlet'         
            ion_velocities = 'zero'
            ion_temperature = 'nose', fnosep = 25, tempw = 300 
        
        /
        &cell
        cell_dynamics = 'pr'
        cell_temperature = 'nose'
        temph = 300
        /
        ATOMIC_SPECIES
         Si  28.0855  Si.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
        
        ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
          Si     0.0000    0.0000    0.0000  1 1 1 
          Si     0.0000    0.5000    0.5000  1 1 1 
          Si     0.5000    0.5000    0.0000  1 1 1 
          Si     0.5000    0.0000    0.5000  1 1 1 
          Si     0.2500    0.2500    0.2500  1 1 1 
          Si     0.2500    0.7500    0.7500  1 1 1 
          Si     0.7500    0.7500    0.2500  1 1 1 
          Si     0.7500    0.2500    0.7500  1 1 1
    
    
        #   nfi    time(ps)        ekinc        T_cell(K)     Tion(K)          etot               enthal               econs               econt          Volume        Pressure(GPa)        EXX               EVDW
     10  1.209442E-03  3.537246E-02  2.010155E+01  3.204737E+00        -46.49326851        -46.49326851        -46.49286026        -45.45750729  6.910778E+02      -0.45178
     20  2.418884E-03  1.326272E-02  1.841089E+01  1.384852E+01        -46.46742938        -46.46742938        -46.46664075        -45.45340706  6.910175E+02      -0.06971
     30  3.628326E-03  3.479818E-02  1.660698E+01  3.056676E+01        -46.49161803        -46.49161803        -46.49021978        -45.45551457  6.909331E+02      -0.81850
     40  4.837769E-03  1.944926E-02  1.509792E+01  4.303143E+01        -46.47695879        -46.47695879        -46.47510836        -45.45590803  6.908187E+02       0.16127
     50  6.047211E-03  2.786502E-02  1.347260E+01  6.490330E+01        -46.48478659        -46.48478659        -46.48212816        -45.45479501  6.906829E+02      -0.38182
     60  7.256653E-03  2.574012E-02  1.262658E+01  7.958814E+01        -46.48347403        -46.48347403        -46.48026960        -45.45554472  6.905094E+02       0.05403
     70  8.466095E-03  2.145223E-02  1.206805E+01  9.466738E+01        -46.48100066        -46.48100066        -46.47723116        -45.45744563  6.903225E+02       0.00761
     80  9.675537E-03  3.123765E-02  1.131623E+01  1.269849E+02        -46.49242102        -46.49242102        -46.48743411        -45.45877920  6.901150E+02      -0.17903
     90  1.088498E-02  1.948726E-02  1.112915E+01  1.826654E+02        -46.47707595        -46.47707595        -46.46997575        -45.45450136  6.898746E+02       0.59737
    100  1.209442E-02  3.243473E-02  1.075638E+01  2.334966E+02        -46.48743968        -46.48743968        -46.47841312        -45.45202659  6.896261E+02      -0.19614
    110  1.330386E-02  2.125317E-02  1.031119E+01  2.979833E+02        -46.47523182        -46.47523182        -46.46376099        -45.45122032  6.893562E+02       0.54842
    120  1.451331E-02  2.841410E-02  9.871604E+00  3.821665E+02        -46.48749266        -46.48749266        -46.47282899        -45.45656870  6.890911E+02       0.54457
    130  1.572275E-02  2.690539E-02  8.963966E+00  4.805864E+02        -46.48830561        -46.48830561        -46.46991475        -45.45932629  6.888169E+02       0.69118
    140  1.693219E-02  2.368875E-02  8.318099E+00  5.737305E+02        -46.48215736        -46.48215736        -46.46023607        -45.45753307  6.885541E+02       1.02291
    150  1.814163E-02  3.043424E-02  6.974218E+00  6.631004E+02        -46.48697501        -46.48697501        -46.46167666        -45.45693830  6.883231E+02       1.13079
    160  1.935107E-02  2.164716E-02  6.223297E+00  7.323270E+02        -46.47554073        -46.47554073        -46.44762234        -45.45582458  6.881316E+02       1.42036
    170  2.056052E-02  3.079481E-02  5.840135E+00  7.858401E+02        -46.48365083        -46.48365083        -46.45370432        -45.45579592  6.879906E+02       1.51860
    180  2.176996E-02  2.469877E-02  6.025400E+00  7.882929E+02        -46.47385608        -46.47385608        -46.44381371        -45.45341864  6.879067E+02       1.47100
    190  2.297940E-02  2.768709E-02  6.652155E+00  7.225444E+02        -46.47688949        -46.47688949        -46.44933675        -45.45564077  6.878883E+02       1.96639
    200  2.418884E-02  2.759704E-02  8.092945E+00  6.061202E+02        -46.46863825        -46.46863825        -46.44548930        -45.45033661  6.879580E+02       1.82407
           9820  1.187672E+00  8.603614E-02  1.643153E+01  2.710110E+02        -46.40789178        -46.40789178        -46.39735874        -45.32909896  7.017371E+02      -0.06544
   9830  1.188882E+00  8.668168E-02  1.808126E+01  2.787074E+02        -46.40621825        -46.40621825        -46.39536922        -45.32698890  7.012214E+02       1.34937
   9840  1.190091E+00  8.607747E-02  2.092269E+01  3.047928E+02        -46.40610715        -46.40610715        -46.39422633        -45.32703275  7.007984E+02       0.06246
   9850  1.191301E+00  8.719006E-02  2.651315E+01  3.342855E+02        -46.41056733        -46.41056733        -46.39748607        -45.32981458  7.004140E+02       0.15200
   9860  1.192510E+00  8.667362E-02  3.140176E+01  3.823131E+02        -46.41121701        -46.41121701        -46.39624096        -45.32973447  7.000836E+02       0.66444
   9870  1.193719E+00  8.750053E-02  3.772695E+01  4.251961E+02        -46.40842448        -46.40842448        -46.39172865        -45.32498198  6.998318E+02       1.26548
   9880  1.194929E+00  8.703085E-02  4.363946E+01  4.324708E+02        -46.40887524        -46.40887524        -46.39181871        -45.32591897  6.996522E+02       0.93973
   9890  1.196138E+00  8.870818E-02  5.062933E+01  4.247125E+02        -46.40891531        -46.40891531        -46.39205400        -45.32459285  6.995423E+02      -0.32813
   9900  1.197348E+00  8.807105E-02  5.592117E+01  4.138435E+02        -46.40532788        -46.40532788        -46.38880419        -45.32185052  6.994674E+02       0.74959
   9910  1.198557E+00  8.799662E-02  6.083216E+01  4.106702E+02        -46.40543239        -46.40543239        -46.38895931        -45.32173637  6.994398E+02       1.36013
   9920  1.199767E+00  8.635629E-02  6.385911E+01  4.111984E+02        -46.40440810        -46.40440810        -46.38787181        -45.32173855  6.994947E+02       0.74635
   9930  1.200976E+00  8.727832E-02  6.617132E+01  4.191855E+02        -46.41052595        -46.41052595        -46.39365318        -45.32582494  6.995763E+02      -0.14401
   9940  1.202186E+00  8.735086E-02  6.840571E+01  4.033592E+02        -46.40912549        -46.40912549        -46.39282232        -45.32393249  6.996844E+02       1.13233
   9950  1.203395E+00  8.855384E-02  6.650079E+01  3.839565E+02        -46.41222450        -46.41222450        -46.39668581        -45.32545979  6.998330E+02       0.76638
   9960  1.204604E+00  8.753365E-02  6.475956E+01  3.459123E+02        -46.41015082        -46.41015082        -46.39608268        -45.32467726  7.000135E+02       1.00947
   9970  1.205814E+00  8.710739E-02  6.091913E+01  2.960265E+02        -46.40785492        -46.40785492        -46.39573726        -45.32365559  7.002347E+02      -0.10449
   9980  1.207023E+00  8.788353E-02  5.736380E+01  2.738816E+02        -46.40891664        -46.40891664        -46.39769119        -45.32385432  7.004349E+02       0.69392
   9990  1.208233E+00  8.947788E-02  5.106475E+01  2.362586E+02        -46.40642617        -46.40642617        -46.39672023        -45.32043641  7.006535E+02       0.85634
  10000  1.209442E+00  8.866628E-02  4.674128E+01  2.045667E+02        -46.40671219        -46.40671219        -46.39827220        -45.32213049  7.008820E+02       0.36617

Here is the cell temperature vs steps

Here is the ion temperature image

This is the last part of the output file
    Averaged Physical Quantities
                      accumulated      this run
   ekinc         :        0.05636       0.05636 (AU)
   ekin          :       12.28236      12.28236 (AU)
   epot          :      -64.01991     -64.01991 (AU)
   total energy  :      -46.44278     -46.44278 (AU)
   temperature   :      300.56059     300.56059 (K )
   enthalpy      :      -46.44278     -46.44278 (AU)
   econs         :      -46.43086     -46.43086 (AU)
   pressure      :        0.00110       0.00110 (Gpa)
   volume        :      696.85979     696.85979 (AU)

